# Resume Alert Dialog state on Back button pressed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, resume

I have to deal with Alert Dialog in my android app. In my first activity there is one alert dialog.On particular action, alert dialog appears. When user clicks yes button of Alert Dialog, user moves to second activity. In my second activity, I have one button. On pressing of this button Alert Dialog should be prompted again with same state. Is it possible to resume the state of Alert Dialog on Back button pressed? code for dialog...

```
// Alert Dialog for input
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    AlertDialog dialogDetails = null;

    switch (id) {

    case DIALOG_LOGIN:
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogbuilder.setView(dialogview);
        dialogDetails = dialogbuilder.create();
        break;

    case LIST_DIALOG :
        LayoutInflater inflater2 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View dialogview1 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.listdialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogbuilder2.setView(dialogview1);
        dialogDetails = dialogbuilder2.create();

    }

    return dialogDetails;
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {

    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_LOGIN:

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
        Button btnSave = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        Button btnCancel = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        etList = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.etList);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                newList = etList.length();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ( newList <= 0) 
                {
                    etList.requestFocus();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Name of List", 1000).show();
                } 

                else 
                {
                    listData = etList.getText().toString().replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
                    if(listData.length() > 0)
                    {
                        dataPass(listData);
                        createfile(listData);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Name of List", 1000).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);
                etList.setText("");
            }
        });

        break;


    case LIST_DIALOG:

        AlertDialog alertDialog1 = (AlertDialog) dialog;

        lvDialog = (ListView) alertDialog1.findViewById(R.id.list1);
        TextView tvAdd = (TextView) alertDialog1.findViewById(R.id.txtAdd);

        tvDone = (TextView) alertDialog1.findViewById(R.id.txtDone);


        if(listName.length() <= 7)
        {
            tvAdd.setText("Add Friends to" +" " + listName );
        }

        else
        {
            tvAdd.setText("Add Friends to" +" " + listName.substring(0, 5) + "..");
        }

        tvDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if( colorRow > 0 )
                {
                    AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewFriendList.this).create();
                    builder.setTitle("Save to List");
                    builder.setMessage("Do You Want to Save?");
                    builder.setButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                        {               
                            removables = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for(int c= 0; c<checked.size(); c++)
                            {
                                int key = checked.keyAt(c);
                                if(checked.get(key, false))
                                {
                                    removables.add(arr2.get(key));
                                    meMap.put(listName, arr2.get(key));
                                }
                            }


                            try 
                            {
                                writeToFile(removables , listName);
                                dismissDialog(LIST_DIALOG);

                            } 
                            catch (IOException e) 
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });

                    builder.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                        {

                            chkText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            colorRow = 0;
                        }

                    });
                    builder.show();
                    }

                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Select Friends", 1000).show();
            }
            });


        lvDialog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                checked = lvDialog.getCheckedItemPositions();
                chkText = (CheckedTextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txt);

                if(checked.get(arg2))
                {
                    chkText.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
                    colorRow ++;
                }
                else
                {

                    chkText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    //colorRow--;
                    colorRow = 0;

                }


            }
        });


        // Cancel Alert Dialog
        ImageView ivCancel = (ImageView) alertDialog1.findViewById(R.id.imgCancel);
        ivCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dismissDialog(LIST_DIALOG); 
                arr2.clear();
        }
        });

        // Friend List
        showFriendList();

        break;

    }
```

Logcat

```
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Displayed com.example.addnewlist/.FinalList: +1s140ms
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:14.259  5320: 5320 D/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Shutting down VM
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:14.259  5320: 5320 W/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:14.290  5320: 5320 E/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4463)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:210)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.example.addnewlist.NewFriendList.onCreateDialog(NewFriendList.java:182)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.example.addnewlist.FinalList$1.onClick(FinalList.java:56)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:14.319   278:  443 W/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):   Force finishing activity com.example.addnewlist/.FinalList
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:14.319   278:  443 W/WindowManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21025
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:14.559   278:  295 I/Choreographer ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:14.559    37:  313 E/SurfaceFlinger ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:14.887   278:  292 W/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{413e8ea0 u0 com.example.addnewlist/.FinalList}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:24.373   278:  292 W/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:24.924   278:  292 W/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{41024d70 u0 com.example.addnewlist/.NewFriendList}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:31.718   599:  617 D/ExchangeService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Received deviceId from Email app: null
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:31.718   599:  617 D/ExchangeService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:36.759   599:  615 D/ExchangeService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:36.769   599:  599 D/ExchangeService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:36.769   599:  599 D/ExchangeService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:36.789   278:  290 W/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:36.789   599:  614 D/ExchangeService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:36.800   278:  442 W/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:36.809   599:  599 E/ActivityThread ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd3578 that was originally bound here
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd3578 that was originally bound here
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:36.819   599:  599 E/StrictMode ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): null
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd3578 that was originally bound here
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:36.819   278:  289 W/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4128da70
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:36.819   599:  599 E/ActivityThread ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfb5d0 that was originally bound here
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfb5d0 that was originally bound here
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:36.839   599:  599 E/StrictMode ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): null
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfb5d0 that was originally bound here
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 08-08 07:14:36.839   278:  418 W/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4128d2f0
```

Answer (score 0):

if your question is is it possible,
Then yes it is.

EDIT

Here is sample code, this might help you.

In your activty A1: Create a `Method` of a `dialog` and pass a parameter Context which will be needed in the second activity to show that `Dialog`. See that

```
public void dialogActivity(final Context c ,int dvalue ){
  if(dvalue==1){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    builder1.setMessage("Please fill all the fields");
    builder1.setCancelable(true);
    builder1.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(c, A2.class);
        startActivity(i);
            dialog.dismiss();
                }
    });

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();
    }
    else{
  AlertDialog.Builder builder12 = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    builder12.setMessage("Please fill all the fields");
    builder12.setCancelable(true);
    builder12.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(c, A2.class);
        startActivity(i);
            dialog.dismiss();
                }
    });

    AlertDialog alert12 = builder12.create();
    alert11.show();

  }
```

Now call that `Dialog` method where you want to, here i am calling it on `backPressed`

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
        dialogActivity(A1.this,1);
}
```

Then in your second activity You have to make an object of Activity A And then you can use that function:

```
  A1 ma = new A1();
```

Then on back pressed of `Activity` you can call your Dialog box.

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    ma.dialogActivity(A2.this,1);
}
```

FYI: Calling activity A2 from itself can show an error.
But here is the way you can achieve dialog box in different activity.

Comment: how? means I have to show it from second activity. Means, alert dialog is in 1st activity and I have to show it from second acitivity.

Comment: In 1st activity there is code of alert dialog, after pressing yes button of dialog, user moves to second activity. now there is one button in second activity say "Back". when user clicks this Back button, alert dialog should prompt again.

Comment: make a function of alertbox with context as a parameter, then call that function anywhere in any class

Comment: I have updated my question...there are two dialogs and I want second one to be prompted.

Comment: put id as a parameter, i guess. If given id matches the dialog id then it will prompt.

Comment: btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Overridepublic void onClick(View v) {
       
NewFriendList obj = new NewFriendList();
obj.onPrepareDialog(LIST_DIALOG1, dialog);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "hello", 1000).show();
    
   }

Comment: private static int LIST_DIALOG1 = 2;
Dialog dialog;

Comment: I passed as parameters to call my second alert dialog, but it's showing Force close error...

Comment: what exactly you want to convey here?

Comment: I created object of First activity in second activity. And on button click, I called that method obj.onPrepareDialog(LIST_DIALOG1, dialog);
with two parameters. I have shown these methods in my questions.

Comment: NewFriendList obj = new NewFriendList();
    obj.onCreateDialog(LIST_DIALOG1);
    obj.onPrepareDialog(LIST_DIALOG1, dialog);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "hello", 1000).show();

Comment: hey log cat is too long to fit in this post

Comment: Try to use my above code in your project, make as many methods and call them, or show me your logcat and whole code which is related to it.

Comment: Check my answer with id , in that way you can display your dialog box

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    showAlertDialog();

}
```

showAlertDialog() function

```
  private void showAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CheckOutScreenActivity.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirmation");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Message").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I have to show Alert dialog from Second Activity's back button.

Comment: In 1st activity there is code of alert dialog, after pressing yes button of dialog, user moves to second activity. now there is one button in second activity say "Back". when user clicks this Back button, alert dialog should prompt again.

Comment: Write the public showAlertDialog() function in first activity and call that function from onBackPressed() of second activity.

Comment: I have updated my question...there are two dialogs and I want second one to be prompted.

Comment: Why u r using onCreate dialog instead of use the functions for alert dialogs, it will be easy for u.

Comment: You mean I can't use that and why?